# Where does the nprogress configuration go in an Aurelia Decorator?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

Having worked through the [Aurelia Contact-Manager tutorial](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/contact-manager-tutorial/1) I'd now like to change the HTML element that the `nprogress` progress bar is rendered against.

I've updated the `src/app.html` by adding an `id` to the `div.container` like so:

```
<template>
  <require from="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"></require>
  <require from="./styles.css"></require>
  <require from="./contact-list"></require>

  <nav> ... </nav>

  <loading-indicator loading.bind="router.isNavigating || api.isRequseting"></loading-indicator>

  <div id="main" class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <contact-list class="col-md-4"></contact-list>
      <router-view class="col-md-8"></router-view>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

.. and according to [the nprogress documentation](https://github.com/rstacruz/nprogress), I need to call the `.configure()` method like so..

```
NProgress.configure({ parent: '#main' });
```

**But where does this line of code go?**  I assume somewhere in `src/resources/elements/loading-indicator.js`..

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct, simply amend `resources/elements/loading-indicator.js`, adding a `constructor()` method to the class where you can call the `.configure()` method (line 8)..

```
import * as nprogress from 'nprogress';
import {bindable, noView, decorators} from 'aurelia-framework';

export let LoadingIndicator = decorators(
  noView(['nprogress/nprogress.css']),
  bindable({name: 'loading', defaultValue: false})
).on(class {
  constructor() {
    nprogress.configure({ parent: '#main' });
  }
  loadingChanged(newValue) {
    if (newValue) {
      nprogress.start();
    } else {
      nprogress.done();
    }
  }
});
```